# Deploy debug visualizer as a VSIX extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugview

is it possible to deploy my debug visualizer with the new extension system in visual studio 2010? I want to publish it on the online gallery and allow to manage it via the extension manager.

The visualizer assembly must be copied to "My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Visualizers"

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible:

> Extension Manager/VSIX doesn't support placing files in the user's documents location, so this isn't possible.

[See here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d16425da-5829-46b7-b2eb-2cedc11fc064)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible via a VSIX, but you can publish MSIs to the Visual Studio Extension Gallery. There are no restrictions on what the MSI can do.