# Debugger Visualizer Deployment as VSIX new possibilities in VS 2012 / 2013

Tags: debugging, vsix, visualizer, debuggervisualizer

I've written an Debugger Visualizer for Html Agility Pack (others will follow):
http://www.crawler-lib.net/visual-studio-debugger-visualizers

I know it wasn't possible to deploy visualizers as VSIX before:
[Deploy debug visualizer as a VSIX extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680445/deploy-debug-visualizer-as-a-vsix-extension)

But they have shown that Visual Studio 2012+ provides new opportunities to do this, at least for nativs /C++:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-graphical-debugger-a17e3d75

Aside from this blog post and a lot of projects using this technique for nativs, I wasn't able to reproduce this for my visualizer. Does anybody know how to do this in VS 2012/2013 or at least additional information about the new opportunities in VS2012/2013 beyond this block post.

Comment: Could you not launch your extension, and do a file copy to the correct folder, then prompt for a VS restart?

Comment: I've thought about this, but it is very ugly. The nativs visualizers don't need that step. If nothing helps I will eventually provide an MSI based installer.

Comment: "Very" ugly is probably a strong word

Comment: Ok, maybe not ugly enough to think about it (seriously)

Comment: A little late to the party, but AFAICT as long as the user doesn't have the visualizer open, even if the user is in the middle of a debugging session, there's no need to restart Visual Studio. This applies even if the user previously opened the visualizer in the current debugging session. @ErikEJ